# Should I provide a recommendation on LinkedIn without being asked?

Tags: references, linkedin

I recently worked with someone who I really enjoyed working with, and who I also think is incredibly skilled. He no longer works with us as he was here on a limited contract which is not being renewed as the work he was hired to do has been finished.

I want to write something about how good he was to work with on his LinkedIn profile, as I genuinely think he was amazing to work with. I am just wondering what the etiquette is for leaving unsolicited recommendations on other people's profiles. Should I hold off from writing anything as he has not asked for a reference?

(Not sure if it's relevant, but we were at the same "level" work-wise, so I was not his manager or anything like that.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By all means do. It doesn't get posted unless the person approves, and it is way better than the "endorsements".

Comment: Ah, I'm new to LinkedIn, and I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm hard-pressed to come up with many cases where someone would be upset that a colleague took the time to add a nice recommendation to their LinkedIn profile.  Barring the odd case where the recommendation is so poorly written or so poorly targeted to the skills the individual wants to demonstrate, in which case LinkedIn allows them to hide the recommendation, your colleague would almost certainly be grateful that you took the time to recommend him or her.  Particularly when your recommendation is genuine as opposed to the many recommendations that occur when A recommends B at the same time that B recommends A because both want to improve their profile.

Comment: I think having feedback that's not targeted to the image that he wants to present is what I'm most concerned about (as some of the things he did used technologies outside his specialty). But I didn't realise he could just hide it if he didn't want others to see it.